# Plugin nativescript-local-notifications triplicates the notification and there's no text

Tags: notifications, nativescript, android-notifications, background-service

I'm using the plugin nativescript-local-notifications on a background service, so when I schedule a notification to right now, it shows 3 notifications (instead of just one), and also there's no text at all:

[image]

My code:

```
  LocalNotifications.schedule({
    title: 'Alerta',
    body: `Uma ocorrência de ${occurrence.category.name} foi registrada próxima ao seu local atual`,
    bigTextStyle: true
  })
```

On the first time I was testing, it was showing 2 notifications, but now it always shows 3 notifications.

Worth mentioning that I'm using nativescript-firebase to receive remote notifications, but this one should be local.

I tested this on an emulator on Android 5.1, but also on both emulator and device running Android 9, and it happens the same thing on all devices.

Comment: Pleas share appropriate code.

Comment: @Manoj sorry, totally forgot the code. I edited the post now.

Comment: Can you include where you have put the local notification code, is it in the remote notification listener? Please include that.

Comment: I actually put it inside my background-service.js (from the other post, if you remember). The code is big, it's like this file: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/background-service.ts

Comment: @Manoj did you check it out?

Comment: Does the notification show up if you run it inside your app, may be at click of a button?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, but the same thing happens in foreground, and now it is showing 4 notifications.

Comment: Can you share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj here you go: https://github.com/DeehSlash/nativescript-local-notifications-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a blunder mistake, neither I noticed it.

`schedule([...])` - expects array of objects, you are passing an object. The program gets confused, try to convert every attribute in the object into a notification, you see as many notification for as many attributes in your object.

Should be,

```
LocalNotifications.schedule([{
    title: 'Alerta',
    body: `Uma ocorrência de ${occurrence.category.name} foi registrada próxima ao seu local atual`,
    bigTextStyle: true
  }])
```

This is why I love working with TypeScript :)